# Expected number of forward jumps to reach a given quantile of a rv

Tags: pr.probability, algorithms, markov-chains, random-walks

I'm a noob in randomized algorithm and ran into a problem(definitely not home work. I'm doing a self study out of my interest with help of my friends. I'm pursuing research career in a machine learning and large scale optimization and found randomized algorithm is being used heavily in this field. In fact in my course of study I encountered a problem, a part of which can be boiled down to this problem) stated below. I tried to form a Markov chain/random walk like formulations but failed.

A master and his student is playing a game as follows:
Suppose there is a machine generating random number , which outputs a number  $x \in [0,1]$ from some fixed distribution $f(x)$ if the button is pressed. Also the machine can be set with a parameter $\rho$ such that it will give a beep sound if the appeared number is greater than or equal to the $(1-\rho)^{th}$-[quantile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) of $f(x)$

At first the master press the button and gets a number .
Next student keeps on pressing until he gets a number which is bigger than the master's number.
Then the master keeps on pressing until his number is bigger than the student's number.
The game goes on like this until the machine gives a beep sound.

What is the expected number of switch over between the student and the master ?

Comment: Whether this was assigned to you or not doesn't matter.

Comment: (1) The distribution might as well be Unif[0,1] since you only care about quantiles. (2) Each time we switch, the new "current max" is distributed independently conditioned on exceeding the old current max. (3) In expectation, each switch cuts the interval in half (first number averages $0.5$, etc), so $\log_2(1/\rho)$ should be the right ballpark.

Comment: @usul: You are assuming that the distribution is continuous. If so, this problem is an easy exercise if you add up the probabilities of changes on each step.

Comment: @DouglasZare, good point about the assumption! But I don't understand your hint.

Comment: The expected number is a sum of probabilities, each of which is easy to compute if the distribution is continuous.

Comment: @DouglasZare, I still don't see how to find a closed form for the probability of occurrence of, say, the 7th or 17th change, let alone a closed form for the infinite sum. I just get a bunch of increasingly nasty integrals. Apologies if I am being dense.

Comment: There are no integrals required. The conditional probability that the $17$th number drawn from a continuous distribution is the largest is $1/17$ by symmetry.

Comment: @DouglasZare, OK I see it now. The expected number of switches is the sum, over the die rolls, of the probability that it is a switch. The probability the $k$th die roll is a switch is the probability that no previous roll exceeded quantile $1-\rho$, times $q_k$, the chance this roll is the highest given that fact. Then $q_k = \rho + (1-\rho)/k$, as with probability $\rho$ this roll is in the highest quanitle, and otherwise it has a $1/k$ chance of being largest thus far. This gives $\sum_k (1-\rho)^{k-1}(\rho + (1-\rho)/k)$. I get this to be exactly $\log(1/\rho)$ not counting the first roll.

Comment: It's a little simpler if you just count the times that there is a greatest-so-far draw below the threshold. You know there will be precisely one draw above the threshold with probability $1$. You can recognize the power series, so there is actually no computation needed.